# Using Implicit Type Syntax on Method Return

Tags: c#, types, methods, implicit, return-type

Not exactly how sure how to title this question, so I hope the title works.

The question is, can I use something similar to implicit type syntax on method calls.  For example, this is the implicit type syntax I am referring to:

```
var x = new Y(){Foo = "Bar", Id = 1};
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
var x = myInstance.CreateItem(){Foo = "Bar", Id = 1};
```

Is there anything in C# that supports something like this?  I don't want to do:

```
x.Foo = "Bar";
x.Id = 1;
...
```

Please note that CreateItem returns a dynamic type.  The CreateItem method and its class cannot be modified.

I would settle for something similar to the With statement in VB.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Attempting Mark Brackett's solution yielded this code:

```
TaskItem item = outlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olTaskItem)._((Action<dynamic>)(i => 
            {
                i.Subject = "New Task";
                i.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
                i.DueDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                i.ReminderSet = false;
                i.Categories = "@Work";
                i.Sensitivity = OlSensitivity.olPrivate;
                i.Display = true;

            }));
```

...

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static T _<T>(this T o, System.Action<dynamic> initialize) where T : class
    {
        initialize(o);
        return o;
    }

}
```

The only problem now is that the extension method doesn't seem to be binding to System._*ComObject because I get this error: System.*_ComObject' does not contain a definition for '_'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called an ["object initializer"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), and no - it's not available for return values (or really, anytime other than with a `new` statement).

Syntax wise, about the closest I can think of would be to use an `Action` delegate (which requires changes to the `Builder`):

```
MyItem CreateItem(Action<MyItem> afterCreate) {
   var i = new MyItem();
   if (afterCreate != null) afterCreate(i);
   return i;
}

var x = Builder.CreateItem(i => { i.Foo = "Bar"; i.Id = 1; });
```

If you're in a JavaScripty mood for short method names for commonly used functions, and can't change the `Builder`, I guess an extension method would also work:

```
public static T _<T>(this T o, Action<T> initialize) where T : class {
    initialize(o);
    return o;
}

var x = Builder.CreateItem()._(i => { i.Foo = "Bar"; i.Id = 1; });
```

> Here's a twist for you. CreateItem() returns a dynamic type

Contrary to my comment, `dynamic` does require a few changes. You need to cast to `object` or the lambda will complain, and then you need to specify `dynamic` as `T` or it'll be inferred as `object`. Or, create your extension method with `Action<dynamic>` and no type arguments.

```
object CreateItem() {
    return (object)Builder.CreateItem();
}

public static dynamic __(this object o, Action<dynamic> initialize) {
    initialize(o);
    return o;
}

var x = CreateItem().__(i => { i.Foo = "Bar"; i.Id = 1; });
```

Comment: Here's a twist for you.  CreateItem() returns a dynamic type.

Comment: @KennyAkridge - shouldn't matter. You may need to make the Action delegate Action<dynamic>, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could use named arguments to the factory method:

```
public static Y Builder.CreateItem(string foo = "", int bar = 0)
{
    return new Y() {Foo = foo, Bar = bar};
}

// called like so:
var x = Builder.CreateItem(Foo: "Bar", Id: 1);
```

Comment: I'm unable to modify the Builder as it is a closed API.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify 'public properties' in the constructor of the class but you cannot do that with methods

because

- This rules only apply to member properties which is not possible with methods
- You can not give public modofier in fields in the method so there is no possibility atall

When you do

```
var a = new MyClass{Foo="",Id=""};
```

You are defining properties of the class of this constructor MyClass()

You cannot do that with static or instance method